# Change TemplateUrl based on URL Params (GET)

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following basic Angular code (test.component.ts) that receives a variable from GET parameters:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-test',
 templateUrl: './test.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})

export class HtmlTablesInputComponent implements OnInit {
 public a:string;
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
 ngOnInit() {
   this.a = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('a'); 
 }
}
```

This coded displays the parameter in the HTML once it receives it.

What I can't do is change the template set in the component (TemplateUrl) from the variable received as a parameter in the GET URL so that it shows you a different HTML based on that variable. That is, if 'Test1.html' comes as a GET parameter, change the set template and instead of displaying ./test.component.html, display ./Test1.html

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use different component based on the query params?

Let's make an example. Query param could have values *[values1, values2]*

You can create two component with the following name (is just an example):

1. **Value1Component**
2. **Value2Component**

After that you load these two components in you template TestComponent (test.component.html).

```
  <div *ngIf="this.a === 'value1'">
    <app-value1></app-value1>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="this.a === 'value2'">
    <app-value2></app-value2>
  </div>
```